# How can I migrate all my Google Photo Albums to another Google account?

Tags: google-photos

I'm trying to migrate all my Google Photo Albums to another Google account, in the sense that all photos and metadata (titles, dates, etc) will be copied into the new account.

Sharing doesn't seem to achieve my goal, as the actual photos remain (physically) in the original account.

The option of downloading and then uploading means that I lose all the actual dates in which photos were taken, and it also means that I have to manually input each and every title (in short, this option does not take care of the metadata).

Any ideas will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i can't test any of this but Google search finds many explanations, this one covers 3 methods - https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/transfer-google-photos-to-another-account-1234.html

Comment: The word "physically" should be changed to "literally", as there is not much physical about electronic files.